# Unable to install OpenVPN on macOS - configure: error: lzo enabled but missing

Tags: macos, configure, openvpn, lzo

I'm trying to install OpenVPN on macOS High Sierra

I have cloned the github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn
```

And switched to the latest stable branch:

```
git checkout origin release/2.4
```

But when I tried to build the project (following the `INSTALL` instructions):

```
autoreconf -i -v -f
./configure
```

I had this error during the `configure` step:

> configure: error: lzo enabled but missing

Even after installing `lzo` dependency with macos ports, the problem persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this problem was easier than I thought...

I had just to define the env vars `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` before running `configure` script:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" 
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"

./configure
make
sudo make install
```

#### UPDATE

If you had to install `lzo`:

- using brew: `brew install lzo` or `brew link lzo` in case it already exists
- using port: `sudo port install lzo`

Comment: I also had to install lzo.
I've been using brew:
`brew install lzo` or `brew link lzo` in case it already exists.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I’ll integrate my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use a M1 MacBook Pro so [freedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50039237/997147) did not work. I had to instead include the library from inside the homebrew directories so my final configure command was:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following resolved the issue for me:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev`

I got this fix from this [askubuntu.com openvpn lzo enabled but missing question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216575/openvpn-configure-error-lzo-enabled-but-missing).

More details: I got each of the 3 error messages shown below separately. Each one was resolved, then I got the next. All 3 are resolved with the one command line above. Basically, 3 developer packages were missing.

- configure: error: OpenSSL version too old (resolved with libssl-dev)
- configure: error: lzo enabled but missing (resolved with liblzo2-dev)
- configure: error: libpam required but missing (resolved with libpam0g-dev)

Thanks to all the other answers which helped to confirm things, triangulate to the answer I felt most confident about!